LTE 4G USB modem not appearing as /dev file
I am running Debian 12 (bookworm)
I recently purchased a data plan/SIM card and an LTE 46 WiFi Dongle.
The SIM card is valid and active.
My goal is to use the device as a modem and issue AT commands to send SMS messages.
When I attach the device to the computer, I expect a /dev/usb* or some other
device to appear within the /dev directory. This does not happen.
After attaching the device ...
lsusb shows this:
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 05c6:f00e Qualcomm, Inc. FP3

dmesg shows this:
[260705.004794] usb 1-3.2: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[260705.106212] usb 1-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=f00e, bcdDevice=ff.ff
[260705.106216] usb 1-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[260705.106218] usb 1-3.2: Product: Android
[260705.106220] usb 1-3.2: Manufacturer: Android
[260705.106221] usb 1-3.2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[260705.109525] rndis_host 1-3.2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2, RNDIS device, 42:8e:91:bb:06:af
[260705.121220] rndis_host 1-3.2:1.0 enx428e91bb06af: renamed from usb0
[260714.255949] usb 1-3.2: USB disconnect, device number 16
[260714.256123] rndis_host 1-3.2:1.0 enx428e91bb06af: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2, RNDIS device
[260714.512937] usb 1-3.2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[260714.614413] usb 1-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=f00e, bcdDevice=ff.ff
[260714.614418] usb 1-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[260714.614420] usb 1-3.2: Product: Android
[260714.614421] usb 1-3.2: Manufacturer: Android
[260714.614422] usb 1-3.2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[260714.617537] rndis_host 1-3.2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2, RNDIS device, 02:00:00:5f:36:32
[260714.626772] rndis_host 1-3.2:1.0 enx0200005f3632: renamed from usb0

udevadm monitor shows this:
KERNEL[260701.881818] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)                                                                                                                                                           
KERNEL[260701.883547] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)                                                                                                                                                 
KERNEL[260701.884833] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0 (net)                                                                                                                                        
KERNEL[260701.884864] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0/queues/rx-0 (queues)                                                                                                                         
KERNEL[260701.884877] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0/queues/tx-0 (queues)                                                                                                                         
KERNEL[260701.885097] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[260701.886476] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[260701.886661] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[260701.886735] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
UDEV  [260701.891643] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
UDEV  [260701.895099] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [260701.895190] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [260701.895454] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[260701.896668] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af (net)
UDEV  [260701.929207] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af (net)
UDEV  [260701.932267] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [260701.932291] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [260701.933016] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [260701.937568] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
UDEV  [260701.939760] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af (net)
KERNEL[260711.032010] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af/queues/rx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[260711.032120] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af/queues/tx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[260711.032190] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af (net)
UDEV  [260711.035044] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [260711.035353] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [260711.038141] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx428e91bb06af (net)
KERNEL[260711.060164] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.060193] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.060211] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.060227] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.061184] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.061210] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.061230] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.061256] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.061736] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.061800] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.063135] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.064075] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.389813] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.391648] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.392866] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0 (net)
KERNEL[260711.392899] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[260711.392911] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[260711.392927] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.393085] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.393110] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.393131] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.396886] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.400305] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.400336] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.400357] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[260711.402053] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx0200005f3632 (net)
UDEV  [260711.424699] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx0200005f3632 (net)
UDEV  [260711.426360] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [260711.426586] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/usb0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [260711.432733] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.437036] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2 (usb)
UDEV  [260711.438935] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.2/1-3.2:1.0/net/enx0200005f3632 (net)

As I said, no /dev/* device appears.
I found a website which said I may need to "switch the USB mode" using the
following command:
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x05c6 -p 0xf00e -V 0x05c6 -P 0xf00e -m "0x01" -M "555342430000000000000000000000110600000000000000000000000000"

I filled in my devices info (from lsusb) and the magic string "555..." and got
this error:
Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0; interface class is 224, expected 8. Abort

I checked dmesg and there were no new messages.
(I do not know what the "magic string" does; I cannot find any info on it.)
The modem supposedly can also act as an AP; its IP is 192.168.100.1
My LAN is 192.168.1.x/24 - I'm not fiddling with my router or net mask so I used
my phone to connect to its network (4G-UFI-056). Connection was successful and
my phone was assigned an IP of 192.168.100.135 but accessing http://192.168.100.1
does nothing but timeout. (I also tried https.) I figured that perhaps the web
interface might have more information that would allow me to use this as a USB
modem.
So I'm dead in the water and I don't know what to try next.
Does anyone have any ideas?

usb-modeswitch is mostly for situations where the device initially presents itself as a USB storage device, containing the Windows/Mac driver for easy installation. Your device did not do that; instead, it presents itself as a network adapter for efficient 4G network access. This is common for 4G and 5G mobile phones and USB modems; the legacy AT command protocol is becoming a rarity. Unfortunately, it looks like the product you purchased may not be usable the way you intended.
